# Is it a good idea to put your hard drive under version control

Tags: version-control

I am thinking of putting all my files under version control in order to be able to reset old files.
I will commit Every day or so adding or removing the changes that I did to the physical drive.

Are there any drawbacks to this? Will it be too space consuming?

Edit: I am thinking about branching capabilities. 
Example: I have a branch with media, a branch with source code, a branch including personal files I wouldn't like to be accessible to every user of my PC, etc..

Comment: My primary concern would be security, following that it would be space in terms of where you would store it. is there a reason you'd prefer to not use typical back-ups or services like Dropbox?

Comment: scm are primary vor textfiles. this is the minority of the files stored on your HD. So this repository will become very fast very large and u can't decide. which version of the files is the one u need.

Comment: @AaronCritchley What about branching capabilities?

Comment: @AngelVenchev I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding you or you completely misunderstand version control. I don't see the benefit of using VCS over any other form of backup, codehitman's answer is more comprehensive and points out a few good reasons as to why it would be troublesome. Sorry to be on the Dropbox train again but simply assigning different permissions to different files and the ability for them to auto-sync seems far better than using something like Git for a purpose it was never intended for.

Comment: There's something interesting going on here if someone is still interested on this topic: [gitfs](https://github.com/PressLabs/gitfs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would depend on what you have on your HDD. If you have your OS on it, then most likely not. OSes tend to create a lot of temporary files; your `.git` will be extremely big. Furthermore, applications also generate a lot of junk, which would be completely useless to put under version control.

But if this is a secondary HDD, and you don't have a lot of files constantly changing, then perhaps. Again for the same reason as above, your git diffs would be extremely large. Even though `git` compresses diffs, it would be almost as large if not more than your actual data (over time). Git isn't designed to be a backup system. Then there is also the concern of security depending where you hope to store your `git` repo. Making your system files publicly accessible is probably not a very good idea.

If you want something close to version-control, at my last workplace we used Crash Plan. Its pretty great. But there is a lot of similar options out there.